# What were IP transactions supposed to be useful for?

Tags: transactions, protocol

Besides sending BitCoins using wallet addresses, there used to be another way, through IP transactions [as described in the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/IP_Transactions).

The disadvantages were obvious (man-in-middle attacks etc).

However, were there *any* benefits (to the individual or to the *whole system*) in using IP transactions?

Comment: You can donate to TOR exit nodes for example ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it needs mentioning that **this functionality has already been removed from the original Bitcoin client**.

Here is the [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/253) removing this functionality that has been accepted 2 years ago. The wiki page you refer to seems outdated.

---

The only known use for IP transactions I could find is the one [mentioned](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/253#issuecomment-1593259) in the pull request by [gmaxwell](https://github.com/gmaxwell):

> Aww. The removal of this would mean we can't run a lottery for nodes running the most recent version of bitcoin as an incentive to make people upgrade. :)

Another use I can come up with myself would be that you could use the DNS system to create a human-readable address to your IP and use that as your payment address. F.e. I could use `bitcoin.stevenroose.be` and put the IP address of the computer running my Bitcoin client in the DNS table for that record. I could then tell people to send bitcoins to that address. However, this method would require a PC to be permanently running and connected to the network in order to be able to receive bitcoins.

Comment: @Pacerier I'm sorry, I read your question wrong. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

IP transactions have been disabled for a long time, and since 0.8 even removed entirely from the source code. The reason was mostly security.

However, there is now work on a [payment protocol](https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/4120476), which is a much more advanced evolution of IP transactions, with built-in (but optional) authentication support.

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe, so you should not use it.
But you are asking about a possible applications...
You could, for instance, integrate IP payments with a bit torrent client, so the people who send you the most of the data would get an incentive for the service they provide you with.